# CoreBluetooth background execution 10sec?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

Because the apple doc is quite vague concerning [this point](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) :

```
 Upon being woken up, an app has around 10 seconds to complete a task
```

Does this mean that after 10 sec the app will go back to its "suspended" state ? Theoretically, is it possible to "force" the app to stay awake after these 10 sec ? (private app).

In my case the device would be connected to a car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that after 10 sec the app will go back to its
>   "suspended" state ?

If you read carefully :

> Upon being woken up, the app has around 10 seconds to process the
>   data. Ideally, it should process the data as fast as possible and
>   allow itself to be suspended again. However, if more time is needed,
>   the app can use the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method
>   to request additional time; it should do so only when absolutely
>   necessary, though.

Apps generally awake by Background modes(like location service, audio, push notification and so on) and for some modes like location service it will stay awake until the location data is being captured and for some, it doesn't stay awake for much time like push notification. So it depends on the task that is being performed. For Bluetooth, if it's connected with another Bluetooth device then it will stay awake.

> Theoretically, is it possible to "force" the app to stay awake after 
>   these 10 sec ? (private app).

Yes, it's possible.

> Each of the preceding modes lets the system know that your app should
>   be woken up or launched at appropriate times to respond to relevant
>   events. For example, an app that begins playing music and then moves
>   to the background still needs execution time to fill the audio output
>   buffers. Enabling the Audio mode tells the system frameworks that they
>   should continue to make the necessary callbacks to the app at
>   appropriate intervals. If the app does not select this mode, any audio
>   being played or recorded by the app stops when the app moves to the
>   background.

Note : If you need it for your private app then you can check this [here](https://github.com/voyage11/Location). Your app will be rejected if you add the solution and apply for appstore.

Comment: From my testing there is no guarantee at all that iOS will let you run for more than 10 seconds even when requesting so. I would keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode, go to your project->Capabilities->Background Modes and mark the Background Modes to On. Mark also Uses Bluetooth LE accessories:

[image]

> Apps that work with Bluetooth peripherals can ask to be woken up if
>   the peripheral delivers an update when the app is suspended. This
>   support is important for Bluetooth-LE accessories that deliver data at
>   regular intervals, such as a Bluetooth heart rate belt. You enable
>   support for using bluetooth accessories from the Background modes
>   section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also
>   enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the
>   bluetooth-central value in your app’s Info.plist file.) When you
>   enable this mode, the Core Bluetooth framework keeps open any active
>   sessions for the corresponding peripheral. In addition, new data
>   arriving from the peripheral causes the system to wake up the app so
>   that it can process the data. The system also wakes up the app to
>   process accessory connection and disconnection notifications.

For more detail you can refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW54).

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Sunil Sharma. Currently the example is related to a accessory who send data such as a heart monitor, I forgot to precise it, but in my case, the device would be connected with a car. this still work ? And the doc talk about woke up the app, but it also precise than we have a window of 10 sec to handle the event, after these 10 sec, the app go back to suspended state ?

Comment: yes, it will still work you have to just select **External accessory communication** in background mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```